# Find out the convex hull of the set $\left\{\pm \mathbf{u} \mathbf{u}^{T} \mid\|\mathbf{u}\|=1\right\}$ in a compact form ($u$ is a n-d vector)

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, convex-hulls, rank-1-matrices

According to the answer from [@Cloudscape](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961061/how-to-find-the-convex-hull-of-a-given-set)

- The first step of finding the convex hull of a given set would be to **visualize** the convex hull and guess it.
- The second step would be to prove your guess contains the set of which you wanted to find the convex hull.
- Next, prove that your guess is convex.
- Finally, prove that any convex set containing the set will include your guess.

But I am struggling with the **first step**, I don't know how to visualize the given set.

Additionally, I also wonder the specific meaning of "compact form".

Comment: Is $uu^T$ the outer product?

Comment: @Kaind exactly!

Comment: Is the first sentence you talking to us, or you reproducing the text of some other source talking to you? If the second, you should blockquote it, and also cite your source. The recommendations in the linked answer might not be helpful in $n^2$ dimensions. (Or are you restricting your vectors specifically to $\Bbb R^2$ or $\Bbb R^3$? If so, you should specify.)

Comment: I don't understand the English of your last sentence. Are you saying you're talking about $\Bbb R^2$, or are you saying you're *not* talking about $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3951902/339790)

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thank you so much!

Comment: Pablo Parrilo, [The convex algebraic geometry of rank minimization](http://web.mit.edu/parrilo/www/pubs/talkfiles/ISMP2009.pdf), International Symposium on Mathematical Programming, August 2009, Chicago.

Comment: Nowhere in your original question did you say you were only talking about two dimensions! That's important information, OP, you shouldn't hide it from us!!

Comment: @runway44 Really sorry about that~ But my teacher does not mention it in problem sets @_@

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thx!!!

Comment: Well then could it be the homework is *not* restricting to 2D? What level of class / homework is this at? Context and background are important. The 2D version and the $n$-dimensional are very different difficulty levels.

Comment: @ runway44 Sorry again I might have misled everyone. Maybe here is not restricted to 2D. It might be in **$n^2$** dimension. It's from a graduate level optimization course.

Answer (score 0):

**Visualization of set:**
A matrix $A$ belongs to that set iff

1. A is symmetric.
2. $a_{ii} > 0 $ & trace(A) = $1$
3. $a_{ij}^2 = a_{ii} a_{jj}$

Can you carry on from here?

Comment: The answer linked by Rodrigo above seems more complex than this hint seems to suggest, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Kaind But how to deal with the sign of $uu^T$ since $trace(−A)=-1$

Comment: @Kaind I also don't know how to use the **third condition** you mentioned to construct convex hull in matrix form

Comment: @Raiden Yeah because that question is $uv^T$ and this question is $uu^T$ i.e. this question is a subset of that question.

Comment: @Kaind yeah $u u^{T}$ is the subset of $u v^{T}$, but here is $\pm u u^{T}$, it's different! In the $u v^{T}$ case we can subsitute v with -v and get $-u v^{T}$, so $\left\{u v^{T}: u \in \mathbb{R}^{m}, v \in \mathbb{R}^{n},\|u\|_{2}=\|v\|_{2}=1\right\} = \left\{-u v^{T}: u \in \mathbb{R}^{m}, v \in \mathbb{R}^{n},\|u\|_{2}=\|v\|_{2}=1\right\}$         
But here we cannot get $-uu^T$ by the same way~

Comment: You can still use their solution to solve your problem.

Comment: I mean $\left\{u v^{T}: u \in \mathbb{R}^{m}, v \in \mathbb{R}^{n},\|u\|_{2}=\|v\|_{2}=1\right\}=\left\{\pm u v^{T}: u \in \mathbb{R}^{m}, v \in \mathbb{R}^{n},\|u\|_{2}=\|v\|_{2}=1\right\}$ But $\left\{\mathbf{u u}^{T} \mid\|\mathbf{u}\|=1\right\}\neq \left\{\pm \mathbf{u u}^{T} \mid\|\mathbf{u}\|=1\right\}$